# jquery : Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'jQuery' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, ng2-bootstrap

I installed [ng2-fullcalendar](https://github.com/nekken/ng2-fullcalendar) calendar in my angualar project. But am getting an error in, path/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts

error message is

> Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable
>   'jQuery' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

When I changed "JQueryStatic" to "any" it works. Since the change is in node_modules directory I cannot make the change for permanently. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options could help:

1. exclude `node_modules` in tsconfig
2. set "skipLibCheck" to `false` in tsconfig.compilerOptions